# Something on CentOS is blocking remote MySQL connection

Tags: centos, mysql, iptables, centos7, selinux

I am running MySQL on CentOS 7, and don't seem to be able to connect MySQL remotely. I have:

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

and certainly not `#skip-networking` but it doesn't matter if I bind to  the actual public/local IP addresses.

I have SELinux disabled:

```
[root@hostname ~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

and output for `iptables -L -v`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 103K   21M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   13   880 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
21423 3952K INPUT_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
21423 3952K INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
21423 3952K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
  166  7863 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
12168 3403K REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 43729 packets, 8473K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 152K   30M OUTPUT_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  ens160 any     anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      any     anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  any    ens160  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  any    +       anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 7423 1336K IN_public  all  --  ens160 any     anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
    0     0 IN_public  all  --  +      any     anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
21423 3952K IN_public_log  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
21423 3952K IN_public_deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
21423 3952K IN_public_allow  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    8   324 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 9081  540K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I certainly did:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '********' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But I think that it is a rather connection issue since:

```
telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 3306
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
telnet: connect to address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

but:

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
mysql -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -u root -p (public IP)
mysql -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -u root -p (local network IP)
```

all seem to work from the console of the server itself. Any thoughts?

Comment: Would be more useful to have output of `iptables -L -v` rather than just `-L` because that adds information about interfaces.

Comment: Just exclude it's a firewall issue: type iptables -t nat -F iptables -t mangle -F iptables -F; as you already have ACCEPT as default policy this will be enough in order to test the service without an iptables ruleset loaded. And please confirm that you can connect to any other mysql server from the client you're using.

Comment: @PaulHaldane updated the question, appreciate the comment and interest.

Comment: @Marco I can confirm that I can connect to other MySQL servers. But I didn't quite get what I need to do with my iptables.

Comment: Type all in one row: "iptables -t nat -f; iptables -t mangle -F; iptables -F". This will unload the firewall rules and keep everything on the default ACCPET. So we can exclude it's a server's firewall issue.

Comment: Output: `iptables v1.4.21: no command specified` I am certainly not the SA you're looking for. (:

Comment: @Marco `sevice iptables stop` certainly resolved the issue, though I am not very comfortable with proceeding like that.

Comment: "iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT" will exclude incoming firewall for all ifs all ips port 3306

Comment: Please, show also `iptables -t nat -L -vn`